# Converting set of InternetAddress to a set of String

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a set of InternetAddress `recipients` which are my recipients. I need to convert it to a Set. I used

```
Set<String> reci = new HashSet<>();
for(InternetAddress recipient : recipients){
    reci.add(recipient.toString());
}
```

which works fine, is it possible to avoid using loop and do this with java 8 map and stream. I tried the following but that didn't work.

```
recipients.stream().map(String::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That gives error 'Cannot resolve constructor String'.

Comment: apart from the problem with `.map(String::new)`, the exact equivalent to constructing a HashSet would be `collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));` as opposed to `collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 5):

The `.map(String::new)` means `element -> new String(element)` and a String constructor with an `InternetAdress` does not exist

You need

```
recipients.stream().map(InternetAddress::toString).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```